# How to transclude component into another component

Tags: angular

I have an angular component and I'm trying to inject a component using trasclusion. The component I want to inject looks like this:

```
<b-upsell-creative
    [channelId]="(context.channel | async)?.id | async">
</b-upsell-creative>
```

I'm trying to include it in my test.component.html like this:

```
<div ng-transclude="b-upsell-creative"></div>
```

but I'm not seeing my component in my dom at all. If I include my `b-upsell-creative` directly in my test.component.html it seems to work though

Comment: ng-transclude is not angular. Basic transclusion example demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6ompz and some info: https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Comment: what do you mean it's not angular? In the angular docs it's a directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: angular !== angularJs

Comment: @Vega oh I see what you mean. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using the tags:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

in my child component and then passing my

`b-upsell-creative` component in the parent component:

```
<div class="parent">
    <b-upsell-creative [channelId]="(context.channel | async)?.id | async">
    </b-upsell-creative>
</div>
```